# Can't get access token using Facebook OAuth

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth, facebook-access-token

About week ago Facebook login on my website worked correctly, but now when I'm trying retrieve access token using "code" I get error "**This authorization code has been used**". I've checked a lot of docs and suggestions, but without any result.

Steps to reproduce(used FB PHP SDK):

1. Send user to FB auth with correct urlencoded return uri(with trailing slash):

   ```
   https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=[my_cid]&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fmydomain.com%2Fauth%2Ffacebook%2F&state=e15e0894cd922098f9f8f340c820538d&scope=email&display=page
   ```
2. Receiving code param on my redirect uri(everything goes fine)
3. Sending request for access token:

   ```
   https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=[my_cid]&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%mydomain.com%2Fauth%2Ffacebook%2F&client_secret=[my_secret]&code=[long_code_goes_here]
   ```

I tried also not urlencoded redirect_uri.

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to Facebook changes that have been optional up until now but will roll out 12/5/12 for everyone.  From the [Developer Roadmap](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/#december-2012) for the Dec '12 breaking changes:

> **New security restrictions for OAuth authorization codes**
>   We will only
>   allow authorization codes to be exchanged for access tokens once and
>   will require that they be exchanged for an access token within 10
>   minutes of their creation. This is in line with the OAuth 2.0 Spec
>   which from the start has stated that "authorization codes MUST be
>   short lived and single use". For more information, check out our
>   Authentication documentation.

So, when you first get an access_token for a user, you need to store it and then explicitly set it the next time the user needs to interact with the FBAPI: $facebook->setAccessToken($theToken);

Comment: so If I get user's token and don't call setAccessToken the very next time, I cannot call it later?